# SVG animation not repeating properly

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

I am having some difficulty getting my SVG icons to repeat properly. I need them to repeat like a gif, individually and indefinitely. I can get only two to work but I need all three to repeat one after the other. Here is a js fiddle of the SVG animation in action. Code below

https://jsfiddle.net/allanberlin/cma0ejkw/

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="loader"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

<g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M46.5,68.5c-2.3,0-4.3-0.8-5.8-2.2l-7.1-7.2c0,0,0,0-0.1-0.1l0,0c-1.4-1.5-2.2-3.6-2.1-6.1
        c0.2-7,6.9-15.7,14.8-19.7c5.3-2.6,10.1-2.5,12.9,0.2l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.1l7,7.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.2l0,0c0.8,1.3,1.2,3,1.2,4.9
        c-0.2,7-6.9,15.8-14.8,19.7C51.1,67.9,48.7,68.5,46.5,68.5z M39.5,61.4l3.2,3.3c1.9,1.9,5.8,1.8,10-0.2c7-3.4,13.2-11.4,13.3-17.4
        c0.1-1.4-0.2-2.5-0.8-3.4l0,0c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.8l-3.1-3.2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2s0,0.2,0,0.3c-0.4,7-6.9,15.5-14.8,19.3l0,0
        c-2.3,1.2-4.6,1.8-6.7,1.8l0,0C39.8,61.4,39.6,61.4,39.5,61.4z M35.5,57.4c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.1,0.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2
        c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1c1.1-6.7,7.3-14.4,14.6-18c1.8-0.9,3.8-1.5,5.4-1.8c-0.1-1.3-0.5-2.4-1.2-3.2
        c0,0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1c-1.9-2-5.8-1.9-10.1,0.2c-7,3.4-13.2,11.4-13.3,17.4C34.1,54.9,34.5,56.4,35.5,57.4L35.5,57.4z M58.6,41.5
        c-1.3,0.2-2.7,0.8-4.1,1.4c-6.4,3.1-11.9,9.8-13.1,15.6c1.3-0.3,2.7-0.8,4.1-1.4l0,0C52,54,57.5,47.3,58.6,41.5z"/>
    <animate id="Circle" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visable" dur="1s" begin="0s; Mona.end"/>
</g>

<g>
   <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M43.2,70.2l-16.1-8l21.4-32.5l24.3,35.2L43.2,70.2z M49.3,35.6l-4.4,31.7l23.4-4.2L49.3,35.6z M30.8,61.2
    L42.3,67l4.1-29.3L30.8,61.2z"/>
         <animate id="Triangle" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visable" dur="1s"  begin="2s; Circle.begin+1s"/>
</g>


<g>
         <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M42.6,68l-20.2-7.1l0.5-1.2c0.3-0.5,5.2-12.5,7.1-16.6l0.2-0.3c1.1-2.4,2.7-5.8,5.7-5.8
c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.2,0.2l0,0l0.2,0.1l9.2,3.2c1,0.3,2.1-0.1,2.5-1.1c0.3-0.6,0.5-1.1,0.6-1.3l0.2-0.3c1.1-2.4,2.7-5.8,5.7-5.8l0,0
c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.2l1.3,0.4l0,0l16.4,5.8c1.8,0.6,2.9,2.4,2.8,4.8c-0.2,1.9-0.6,3.3-1.2,4.9l-0.4,1.2l-5.2-1.8
c-1-0.3-2.1,0.1-2.5,1.1c-1.9,4.4-4.9,11.3-4.9,11.4l-0.2,0.3c-1,2.1-2.2,4.6-5.1,3.9l0,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.4-0.2l0,0
c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c-0.9-0.3-3.3-1.2-9.8-3.5c-1-0.3-2.1,0.1-2.5,1.1C44,64.6,43,66.9,43,66.9L42.6,68z M27.9,60.1l11.5,4
c1,0.3,2.1-0.1,2.5-1.1c0.6-1.4,1.4-3.3,2.2-5.2l0,0c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5l0.3-0.6l0,0c1.1-2.7,2.4-5.8,3.2-7.4l0.2-0.3
c0.4-0.7,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.4c0.6-1.1,0.1-2.4-1-2.9l-11.5-4c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2l-0.2,0.3
c-1.3,2.7-4.1,9.3-5.8,13.3C26.2,58.5,26.8,59.7,27.9,60.1z M58.8,61.8c0.7,0.2,1.1-0.3,2.2-2.5l0.2-0.2c0-0.1,4.8-11.3,6.2-14.2
l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.5-1.1l0,0c0.3-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.1-2.2c0.6-1.1,0.1-2.4-1-2.8l-11.5-4c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1l0,0
c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2l-0.2,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.3,1.2,2.6l2.4,0.8l0,0c0.5,0.2,1,0.5,1.3,0.8
c0.9,0.9,1.4,2.5,1.4,4.5L58,59.3c0,0.7,0.2,1.9,0.7,2.2C58.6,61.7,58.7,61.7,58.8,61.8z M47.8,55.6c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.3,1.2,2.7
c2,0.7,4.4,1.5,6.3,2.2c-0.1-0.6-0.1-1-0.1-1.2l0.1-10.5c0-1.2-0.3-2.2-0.7-2.7c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2l0,0l0,0
c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2L50,50.4C49.5,51.6,48.7,53.6,47.8,55.6z M72.3,45.3L72.3,45.3
c1.2,0.4,2.4-0.3,2.6-1.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7c0.1-0.7,0-1.8-1-2.2l0,0c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.1l0,0c-0.8,0-1.4,0.7-2,1.5
C70.6,43.4,71.1,44.8,72.3,45.3z"/>
    <animate id="Mona" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visable" dur="1s" begin="3s; Triangle.begin+1s"/>
</g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**visible** has two i's and no a.

Do you really want everything to appear at once. If not make the groups hidden by default as I've done.

```css
body {
  background-color: #aad5df;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="loader"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
         
<g visibility="hidden">
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M46.5,68.5c-2.3,0-4.3-0.8-5.8-2.2l-7.1-7.2c0,0,0,0-0.1-0.1l0,0c-1.4-1.5-2.2-3.6-2.1-6.1
  c0.2-7,6.9-15.7,14.8-19.7c5.3-2.6,10.1-2.5,12.9,0.2l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.1l7,7.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.2l0,0c0.8,1.3,1.2,3,1.2,4.9
  c-0.2,7-6.9,15.8-14.8,19.7C51.1,67.9,48.7,68.5,46.5,68.5z M39.5,61.4l3.2,3.3c1.9,1.9,5.8,1.8,10-0.2c7-3.4,13.2-11.4,13.3-17.4
  c0.1-1.4-0.2-2.5-0.8-3.4l0,0c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.8l-3.1-3.2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2s0,0.2,0,0.3c-0.4,7-6.9,15.5-14.8,19.3l0,0
  c-2.3,1.2-4.6,1.8-6.7,1.8l0,0C39.8,61.4,39.6,61.4,39.5,61.4z M35.5,57.4c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.1,0.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2
  c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1c1.1-6.7,7.3-14.4,14.6-18c1.8-0.9,3.8-1.5,5.4-1.8c-0.1-1.3-0.5-2.4-1.2-3.2
  c0,0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1c-1.9-2-5.8-1.9-10.1,0.2c-7,3.4-13.2,11.4-13.3,17.4C34.1,54.9,34.5,56.4,35.5,57.4L35.5,57.4z M58.6,41.5
  c-1.3,0.2-2.7,0.8-4.1,1.4c-6.4,3.1-11.9,9.8-13.1,15.6c1.3-0.3,2.7-0.8,4.1-1.4l0,0C52,54,57.5,47.3,58.6,41.5z" />
    <animate id="Circle" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" dur="1s" begin="0s; Mona.end"/>
</g>
<g visibility="hidden">
   <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M43.2,70.2l-16.1-8l21.4-32.5l24.3,35.2L43.2,70.2z M49.3,35.6l-4.4,31.7l23.4-4.2L49.3,35.6z M30.8,61.2
 L42.3,67l4.1-29.3L30.8,61.2z"/>
         <animate id="Triangle" from="hidden" to="visible" dur="1s" attributeName="visibility" begin="Circle.begin+1s"/>
</g>


<g visibility="hidden">
         <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M42.6,68l-20.2-7.1l0.5-1.2c0.3-0.5,5.2-12.5,7.1-16.6l0.2-0.3c1.1-2.4,2.7-5.8,5.7-5.8
c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.2,0.2l0,0l0.2,0.1l9.2,3.2c1,0.3,2.1-0.1,2.5-1.1c0.3-0.6,0.5-1.1,0.6-1.3l0.2-0.3c1.1-2.4,2.7-5.8,5.7-5.8l0,0
c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.2l1.3,0.4l0,0l16.4,5.8c1.8,0.6,2.9,2.4,2.8,4.8c-0.2,1.9-0.6,3.3-1.2,4.9l-0.4,1.2l-5.2-1.8
c-1-0.3-2.1,0.1-2.5,1.1c-1.9,4.4-4.9,11.3-4.9,11.4l-0.2,0.3c-1,2.1-2.2,4.6-5.1,3.9l0,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.4-0.2l0,0
c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c-0.9-0.3-3.3-1.2-9.8-3.5c-1-0.3-2.1,0.1-2.5,1.1C44,64.6,43,66.9,43,66.9L42.6,68z M27.9,60.1l11.5,4
c1,0.3,2.1-0.1,2.5-1.1c0.6-1.4,1.4-3.3,2.2-5.2l0,0c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5l0.3-0.6l0,0c1.1-2.7,2.4-5.8,3.2-7.4l0.2-0.3
c0.4-0.7,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.4c0.6-1.1,0.1-2.4-1-2.9l-11.5-4c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2l-0.2,0.3
c-1.3,2.7-4.1,9.3-5.8,13.3C26.2,58.5,26.8,59.7,27.9,60.1z M58.8,61.8c0.7,0.2,1.1-0.3,2.2-2.5l0.2-0.2c0-0.1,4.8-11.3,6.2-14.2
l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.5-1.1l0,0c0.3-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.1-2.2c0.6-1.1,0.1-2.4-1-2.8l-11.5-4c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1l0,0
c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2l-0.2,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.3,1.2,2.6l2.4,0.8l0,0c0.5,0.2,1,0.5,1.3,0.8
c0.9,0.9,1.4,2.5,1.4,4.5L58,59.3c0,0.7,0.2,1.9,0.7,2.2C58.6,61.7,58.7,61.7,58.8,61.8z M47.8,55.6c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.3,1.2,2.7
c2,0.7,4.4,1.5,6.3,2.2c-0.1-0.6-0.1-1-0.1-1.2l0.1-10.5c0-1.2-0.3-2.2-0.7-2.7c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2l0,0l0,0
c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2L50,50.4C49.5,51.6,48.7,53.6,47.8,55.6z M72.3,45.3L72.3,45.3
c1.2,0.4,2.4-0.3,2.6-1.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7c0.1-0.7,0-1.8-1-2.2l0,0c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.1l0,0c-0.8,0-1.4,0.7-2,1.5
C70.6,43.4,71.1,44.8,72.3,45.3z"/>
    <animate id="Mona" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" dur="1s" begin="Triangle.begin+1s"/>
</g>
         
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't know who you are or where you are from but I love you :D Thank you so much for the help. Racking my brain all day

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, but without the flashing.

```css
body {
  background-color: #aad5df;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="loader"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
         
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M46.5,68.5c-2.3,0-4.3-0.8-5.8-2.2l-7.1-7.2c0,0,0,0-0.1-0.1l0,0c-1.4-1.5-2.2-3.6-2.1-6.1
  c0.2-7,6.9-15.7,14.8-19.7c5.3-2.6,10.1-2.5,12.9,0.2l0.1,0.1l0.1,0.1l7,7.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.2l0,0c0.8,1.3,1.2,3,1.2,4.9
  c-0.2,7-6.9,15.8-14.8,19.7C51.1,67.9,48.7,68.5,46.5,68.5z M39.5,61.4l3.2,3.3c1.9,1.9,5.8,1.8,10-0.2c7-3.4,13.2-11.4,13.3-17.4
  c0.1-1.4-0.2-2.5-0.8-3.4l0,0c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.8l-3.1-3.2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2s0,0.2,0,0.3c-0.4,7-6.9,15.5-14.8,19.3l0,0
  c-2.3,1.2-4.6,1.8-6.7,1.8l0,0C39.8,61.4,39.6,61.4,39.5,61.4z M35.5,57.4c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.1,0.8c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2
  c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.1c1.1-6.7,7.3-14.4,14.6-18c1.8-0.9,3.8-1.5,5.4-1.8c-0.1-1.3-0.5-2.4-1.2-3.2
  c0,0-0.1,0-0.1-0.1c-1.9-2-5.8-1.9-10.1,0.2c-7,3.4-13.2,11.4-13.3,17.4C34.1,54.9,34.5,56.4,35.5,57.4L35.5,57.4z M58.6,41.5
  c-1.3,0.2-2.7,0.8-4.1,1.4c-6.4,3.1-11.9,9.8-13.1,15.6c1.3-0.3,2.7-0.8,4.1-1.4l0,0C52,54,57.5,47.3,58.6,41.5z" visibility="hidden">
        <set id="Circle" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible"
             begin="0s; Mona.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
        <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden"
             begin="Circle.end" fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
</g>
 
<g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M43.2,70.2l-16.1-8l21.4-32.5l24.3,35.2L43.2,70.2z M49.3,35.6l-4.4,31.7l23.4-4.2L49.3,35.6z M30.8,61.2
 L42.3,67l4.1-29.3L30.8,61.2z" visibility="hidden">
        <set id="Triangle" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible"
             begin="Circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
        <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden"
             begin="Triangle.end" fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
</g>


<g>
         <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M42.6,68l-20.2-7.1l0.5-1.2c0.3-0.5,5.2-12.5,7.1-16.6l0.2-0.3c1.1-2.4,2.7-5.8,5.7-5.8
c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.2,0.2l0,0l0.2,0.1l9.2,3.2c1,0.3,2.1-0.1,2.5-1.1c0.3-0.6,0.5-1.1,0.6-1.3l0.2-0.3c1.1-2.4,2.7-5.8,5.7-5.8l0,0
c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.2l1.3,0.4l0,0l16.4,5.8c1.8,0.6,2.9,2.4,2.8,4.8c-0.2,1.9-0.6,3.3-1.2,4.9l-0.4,1.2l-5.2-1.8
c-1-0.3-2.1,0.1-2.5,1.1c-1.9,4.4-4.9,11.3-4.9,11.4l-0.2,0.3c-1,2.1-2.2,4.6-5.1,3.9l0,0c0,0-0.1,0-0.4-0.2l0,0
c-0.1,0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1c-0.9-0.3-3.3-1.2-9.8-3.5c-1-0.3-2.1,0.1-2.5,1.1C44,64.6,43,66.9,43,66.9L42.6,68z M27.9,60.1l11.5,4
c1,0.3,2.1-0.1,2.5-1.1c0.6-1.4,1.4-3.3,2.2-5.2l0,0c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5l0.3-0.6l0,0c1.1-2.7,2.4-5.8,3.2-7.4l0.2-0.3
c0.4-0.7,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.4c0.6-1.1,0.1-2.4-1-2.9l-11.5-4c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2l-0.2,0.3
c-1.3,2.7-4.1,9.3-5.8,13.3C26.2,58.5,26.8,59.7,27.9,60.1z M58.8,61.8c0.7,0.2,1.1-0.3,2.2-2.5l0.2-0.2c0-0.1,4.8-11.3,6.2-14.2
l0,0l0,0l0,0l0,0l0.5-1.1l0,0c0.3-0.7,0.7-1.5,1.1-2.2c0.6-1.1,0.1-2.4-1-2.8l-11.5-4c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1l0,0
c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2l-0.2,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.3,1.2,2.6l2.4,0.8l0,0c0.5,0.2,1,0.5,1.3,0.8
c0.9,0.9,1.4,2.5,1.4,4.5L58,59.3c0,0.7,0.2,1.9,0.7,2.2C58.6,61.7,58.7,61.7,58.8,61.8z M47.8,55.6c-0.5,1.1,0.1,2.3,1.2,2.7
c2,0.7,4.4,1.5,6.3,2.2c-0.1-0.6-0.1-1-0.1-1.2l0.1-10.5c0-1.2-0.3-2.2-0.7-2.7c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2l0,0l0,0
c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.1c-1.5,0-2.6,2.3-3.4,4.2L50,50.4C49.5,51.6,48.7,53.6,47.8,55.6z M72.3,45.3L72.3,45.3
c1.2,0.4,2.4-0.3,2.6-1.5c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7c0.1-0.7,0-1.8-1-2.2l0,0c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.1l0,0c-0.8,0-1.4,0.7-2,1.5
C70.6,43.4,71.1,44.8,72.3,45.3z" visibility="hidden">
        <set id="Mona" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible"
             begin="Triangle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
        <set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden"
             begin="Mona.end" fill="freeze"/>
    </path>
</g>
         
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I got it working, but this will be useful for in future :)